# Server 2012 Windows 8.1EE new users not inheriting GPO setup

Tags: windows, group-policy

I manage a couple of schools with Server 2012R2 & Windows 8.1 EE. This particular school has had the same setup for the last two years and as usual, during the summer break I apply the latest Windows updates to the Server and Clients. I also delete pupils and staff that have left and add in new pupils and staff. We use roaming profiles and home folders on the server so anyone can use any desktop/laptop. All fairly simple and usually works fine.

I've added new pupils and staff as usual into the correct policy groups and tested that they can log on. Their user profile folder gets created on the server but nothing gets written into it - I've hovered the mouse over the folder which shows as empty whereas working profile folders show some contents listed. At the client machine none of the GPO policies get applied, no drive mapping, printer assignments, same desktop/start screen as if you'd logged onto the machine locally. I've verified that the users are in the correct policy groups, tried different client machines, additional test users but still the same problem. It seems that users with existing profiles work correctly on the domain but new users don't.

Interestingly, some existing users whose profiles I had deleted had the same issue when a new replacement profile was created. However, when I deleted the server profile and then logged them on via a client machine that had a previous domain profile for them stored locally their profile was created successfully on the server when they logged off...

I've changed nothing and done nothing differently to normal so I'm wondering if one of the updates is causing the problem. Any advice gratefully received...

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly related to this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2016/06/22/deploying-group-policy-security-update-ms16-072-kb3163622

Comment: Indeed it was. Thanks very much for pointing me to this article. I owe you a pint at least !

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding authenticated users with read access only to all the GPO's being applied on a user/user group basis.

Thanks to joeqwerty for posting this link  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2016/06/22/deploying-group-policy-security-update-ms16-072-kb3163622